# Fastest way to select an option using selenium?

Tags: c#, testing, xpath, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a UI test that is failing on one dropdown that has a lot of options in it (greater than 1000). The error message is "The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL ... timed out after 60 seconds".

Now I acknowledge that it is not good practice having that many options in a dropdown but I can't change that at the moment. That being said, what is the fastest way to select an option by text using Selenium? Could I gain any speed using xpath to find the option or is there some other way to do it? Thanks.

Here is my current code:

```
            var fieldElement = driver.FindElement(dropDownLocator);
            var select = new SelectElement(fieldElement);
            select.SelectByText(value);
```

Comment: My understanding is that xpath is much slower than CSS in Selenium.  For a dropdown that size, you may want to consider a javascript executor approach.  Possibly you can use an approach to select the specific option you want to click, instead of the SelectElement approach.

Comment: Underneath it all, the `SelectElement` uses XPath to find the `select`'s child `option` elements. What exactly is slow? The initial find of the `select` or selecting an `option` by it's `text`?

Comment: Arran - Finding the select is fast, but selecting a specific option based on its text is the part that's slow and timing out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing. I use IJavaScriptExecutor and wrote a script to find the first option in a list with specific text. This solution isn't perfect, if in my test I select an option at the bottom of list it may still time out. In my situation the option doesn't affect functionality at all so I can pick an option near the top of the list and it will find it quickly.

```
var fieldElement = driver.FindElement(dropDownLocator);                       
var js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
var script = string.Format("$('#{0} option').each(function (){{if($(this).text() == \"{1}\"){{$(this).attr('selected', true);return false;}}}});", fieldElement.GetAttribute("id"), value);
js.ExecuteScript(script);
```

Comment: Wow thanks for this awsome solution. By using `script` insteed of `SelectElement`, I was able to reduce my test from running for 6 minutes to 15 seconds. Going to stay away from `SelectElement`.

Answer (score 1):

It has been my understanding (and practice) that using the `id` is the fastest way to interact with a selector in Selenium.  Here are some example selectors that I use in my automated code:

```
@FindBy(css = "p.productSKU") protected WebElement skuVal;
@FindBy(id="sku") protected WebElement sku; 
@FindBy(className = "reducedPrice") protected List<WebElement> reducedPrice;
```

The `FindBy Interface` within Selenium will allow you to use the following, however:

```
id, xpath, using, css, name, className, tabName, linkText, and partialLinkText
```

I always prefer to use id and xpath, personally.  But, depending on what you are automating and how it is/was developed, the other mechanisms can become necessary as well.